# Detect if browser has TLS enabled

Tags: javascript, html, ssl

Is there a way to check if a browser has TLS enabled?

I'm limited to using HTML and Javascript.

Comment: Is it sufficient to test if the browser supports either SSL or TLS, or do you want to test TLS specifically?  If you just want to test HTTPS support, I would send an Ajax request for a page over HTTPS.

Comment: @apsillers +, We want to verify TLS. If necessary, we will use a method similar to this.

Comment: I don't think any browser less than 7-8 years old doesn't support TLS 1.0 at least. Disabling it wouldn't make sense (but could happen indeed).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Javascript, utilizing ActiveX, and intended for IE7,

```
(function(){
var key = "HKCU\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Internet Settings\\SecureProtocols";
var t = document.getElementById("detectREG_output");
var Shell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var value = Shell.RegRead(key);
t.innerHTML = value;
})();
```

This outputs a bitfield, with decimals equating to:

168 = SSL 3.0, SSL 2.0, TLS 1.0 Enabled

160 = SSL 3.0, TLS 1.0          Enabled

40  = SSL 3.0, SSL 2.0  Enabled

8 = SSL 2.0 Enabled

0 = None are enabled

[MSDN on IE7 and HTTPS](https://web.archive.org/web/20070505012444/http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/IETechCol/cols/dnexpie/ie7_https_imps.asp)

Comment: Are there javascript libraries out there that could do this for other browsers also? Our ssl website host has disabled TLS 1.0 and down. We need to inform site visitors to upgrade their browser in a user friendly way. Currently what they get is either a blank page or some cryptic error message.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I can find is configuring apache to respect a certain order of cipher :

```
SSLCipherSuite !aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DSS:!DES:!SSLv2:RC4-SHA:RC4-MD5:ALL
SSLHonorCipherOrder on
```

for example. And Then in a PHP page (behind a https) display $_ENV['SSL_PROTOCOL']. Finally use the result in JS.

Comment: The cipher suite selection here could apply to both SSLv3 and TLS. You'd need something like `SSLProtocol -SSLv3 -SSLv2 +TLSv1`.