# Is there a way to check if TLS is enabled?

Tags: internet-explorer, ssl, https

I need to check if TLS is enabled on certain versions of IE (specifically 8 through 11) for a web project. Is this something that is possible?

I have checked Microsoft's website already and there doesn't appear to be anything beyond a script meant for IE 7. I've also looked here and only found two questions asking about this, one of which had the script for IE 7 as the answer. Links to all three pages can be found below.

- [Detect if browser has TLS enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985519/detect-if-browser-has-tls-enabled)
- [Checking the TLS version in
  browser requests to https connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19443469/checking-the-tls-version-in-browser-requests-to-https-connection)
- [Microsoft IE 7 HTTPS
  improvements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250503%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Well the answer is that it is, in all those cases, unless you're talking about the actual configuration of individual installations?

Comment: I'm trying to see if TLS is enabled and if SSL v3 is enabled on a browser that loads the page.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a table [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Web_browsers) that describes support for various browsers. I would recommend using the best that both browser and server support as a general rule.

If you have specific concerns perhaps a new question that describes those concerns and gives use cases would be a good way to find guidance.